# Proof writing involving propositional logic: (p∧ (¬q) ) ↔ ((¬p) ∧ q) ≡ p ↔ q

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

**Prove by using propositional logic:**

(p∧ (¬q) ) ↔ ((¬p) ∧ q) ≡  p ↔ q

Is this possible? I tried solving but i get stuck.

LS:

= (p∧ (¬q) ) ↔ ((¬p) ∧ q)

= ((p∧ (¬q) ) →  ((¬p) ∧ q) )  ∧ ( ((¬p) ∧ q)  → (p∧ (¬q) ))

= (¬(p∧ (¬q) ) ∨ ((¬p) ∧ q)) ∧ ¬((¬p) ∧ q) ∨ (p∧ (¬q) )

= ((¬p) ∨ q)  ∨ ((¬p) ∧ q)) ∧ ((p ∨ (¬q)) ∨ (p∧ (¬q) ))

= (¬p ∨ ((¬p) ∧ q)) ∨ (q ∨ ((¬p) ∧ q))) ∧ ((p ∨ (p∧ (¬q) )) ∨ ((¬q) ∨ (p∧ (¬q)))

= (T ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∨ (q ∨ ¬p) ∧ q ) ∧ (p ∧ (p ∨ (¬q) ) ∨ (q v p) ∧ T)

= ((¬p ∨ q) ∨ ((q ∨ ¬p) ∧ q) ) ∧ ( (p ∧ (p ∨ (¬q) )) ∨ (q v p))

=...

I assume this would be true since ( p ∨ q)  ↔ ( p ∧ q ) ≡ p  ↔ q is true. 
Proved that already. What you guys think? Is it possible to keep breaking this statement down till p ↔ q ? am i missing some identities?

**Edit:** worked a truth table so both statements are equivalent. However, I need to prove this by propositional logic. Any help?

Comment: I'd make a truth table and solve the problem that way.

Comment: Yes that's the easy route but not allowed. Thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
LHS&\equiv((p∧ ¬q)\to(¬p ∧ q)) \land ((¬p ∧ q)\to(p∧ ¬q)) 
\\
&\equiv ((\neg p\lor q)\lor(¬p ∧ q)) \land ((p \lor \neg q)\lor(p∧ ¬q))
\\
&\equiv (((\neg p\lor q)\lor¬p)\land ((\neg p\lor q)\lor q)) \land (((p \lor \neg q)\lor p)\land ((p \lor \neg q)\lor ¬q))
\\
&\equiv ((\neg p\lor q)\land (\neg p\lor q)) \land ((p \lor \neg q)\land ((p \lor \neg q))
\\
&\equiv (\neg p\lor q) \land (p \lor \neg q)
\\
&\equiv (p\to q) \land (q\to p)
\\
&\equiv (p↔ q)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Hermes. how did you break this down? ≡(((¬p∨q)∨¬p)∧((¬p∨q)∨q))∧(((p∨¬q)∨p)∧((p∨¬q)∨¬q))

Comment: $(\neg p\lor q)\lor¬p\equiv (\neg p\lor \neg p)\lor q\equiv\neg p \lor q$ and so on.

Comment: By distributivity, $(\neg p\lor q)\lor(¬p ∧ q)=((\neg p\lor q)\lor¬p)\land ((\neg p\lor q)\lor q)$

Comment: Gotcha. I was not seeing that. Thanks a lot L:) @hermes